# Verificar 2 valores depois do . (ponto)

Tags: php, datetime, data

Estou desenvolvendo um código aonde eu tenho que calcular diárias de um estacionamento. Caso o usuário selecione por exemplo:

> De: 05-11-2015 15:00 Até 06-11-2015 15:00

O valor a ser retornado é **1**, ou seja, 1 diária.
Caso o usuário selecione:

> De: 05-11-2015 15:00 Até 06-11-2015 16:00

O valor a ser retornado vai ser **1.xxxxx**
E assim por diante. O que preciso saber é se existir um valor depois do . (ponto) então quer dizer que é mais uma diária além do valor da esquerda (que no caso do exemplo é 1).

O código que tenho atualmente é

```
<?php
$entrada = strtotime('2015-11-05 10:00');
$saida = strtotime('2015-11-10 11:00');

$diaria = ($saida-$entrada) / (60*60*24);

echo $diaria;
?>
```

Ele faz o calculo certo, só preciso mesmo saber se tem algum valor depois do . para contar como + 1 diária.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente usar a função [ceil](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ceil.php), acho que te ajuda nesse caso.

Abraço

Comment: É, foi essa solução que pensei quando escrevi o post. Realmente funcionou, obrigado!